# How to get top 1 records from a query

Tags: linq

Say there are 5 records from the query, how do I get the top 1 records? This is my current code.

```
public Application GetByUserIdAndVersion(int userId, string version)
{
    VettingDataContext dc = new VettingDataContext(_connString);
    return (from a in dc.Applications
            where a.UserId == userId && a.chr_Version == version
            select a).SingleOrDefault<Application>();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `FirstOrDefault()` instead:

```
return (from a in dc.Applications
        where a.UserId == userId && a.chr_Version == version
        select a).FirstOrDefault<Application>();
```

`SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception if there is more than one record, `FirstOrDefault()` will just take the first one.

Also you shouldn't have to cast to `Application` - your record already is of type `Application`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first record you can try:

```
return (from a in dc.Applications where a.UserId == userId && a.chr_Version == version select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

For the first N use:

```
return (from a in dc.Applications where a.UserId == userId && a.chr_Version == version select a).Take(N);
```